# How to convert Excel to semicolon or pipe delimited file using script?

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, automation

I am trying to automate task of converting an Excel workbook to a CSV file. The resulting file should be semicolon and pipe delimited. However I am getting comma separated files only. I tried playing with `SaveAs` parameters, but no help.

Can somebody suggest a way to do this in VBScript.

Here is my code that is able to convert workbook to CSV. I even tried to replace comma with pipe or semicolon, but that was super buggy resulting in incorrect data.

```
Dim strExcelFileName
Dim strCSVFileName
strDelimiter = "|"

strExcelFileName = "file_temp" '

Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
strScript = WScript.ScriptFullName
strScriptPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(strScript & "\..")
WScript.Echo strScriptPath

'If the Input file is NOT qualified with a path, default the current path
LPosition = InStrRev(strExcelFileName, "\")
If LPosition = 0 Then 'no folder path
    strExcelFileName = strScriptPath & "\file\" & strExcelFileName
    strScriptPath = strScriptPath & "\"
Else 'there is a folder path, use it for the output folder path also
    strScriptPath = Mid(strExcelFileName, 1, LPosition)
End If
'MsgBox LPosition & " - " & strExcelFileName & " - " & strScriptPath  ' use this for debugging

Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkBook = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strExcelFileName)
objXL.DisplayAlerts = False

'loop over worksheets
For Each sheet In objWorkBook.Sheets
    'only saveAS sheets that are NOT empty
    If objXL.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        sheet.Rows(1).Delete  ' this will remove Row 1 or the header Row
        Select Case sheet.Name 
        Case "Sales"
            sheet.SaveAs strScriptPath & "abc_sales.csv", 23, local=true 'CSV
        Case "Goals"
            sheet.SaveAs strScriptPath & "abc_file_goals.csv", 6 'CSV
        Case "Commissions"
            sheet.SaveAs strScriptPath & "abc_file_coms.csv", 6 'CSV
        Case Else
            sheet.SaveAs strScriptPath & "abc_file_coms.csv", 6 'CSV
        End Select
    End If
Next

'clean up
objWorkBook.Close
objXL.Quit
Set objXL = Nothing
Set objWorkBook = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

**Edit** I have tried below code to force local setting and windows csv format. but it is stil generating comma separated file. Local setting is set as pipe.

```
sheet.SaveAs strScriptPath & "abc.csv", 23, local=true
```

Comment: You're trying to use `xlCSV` in your code, but never define it anywhere. VBScript doesn't know about vBA constants.

Comment: yes, I mixed vba and vbscript :-(, still trying to learn how can I achieve this in vbscript.

Comment: You need to define the constant yourself or use its [numeric value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel). See [here](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml) for general help on translating VBA to VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

**test it:**  UPDATED (Field `local` it is  position **10!** )

--*for VBScript*--
, , , , , , , , , , True
  last position is 'local' 
(ty @Lankymart)

--*for VBA*-- 
FileFormat := xlCSVWindows, Local := True

then delimiter from regional settings

---

**Default is**

Local := False (Default) 
Always ','

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel

**Workbook.SaveAs Method (Excel)**

**Syntax**

*expression* . SaveAs( FileName , FileFormat , Password , WriteResPassword , ReadOnlyRecommended , CreateBackup , AccessMode , ConflictResolution , AddToMru , TextCodepage , TextVisualLayout , Local )

**Local** *Optional Variant*

True saves files against the language of Microsoft Excel (including control panel settings). False (default) saves files against the language of Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) (which is typically US English unless the VBA project where Workbooks.Open is run from is an old internationalized XL5/95 VBA project).

**BUT** in column `Description` for TextVisualLayout and TextCodepage write:

> Ignored for all languages in Microsoft Excel.

IMHO therefore the number of arguments in the function is reduced from 12 to 10

---

And set format of the file to 23:

[XlFileFormat Enumeration (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel)

*Name  Value  Description*

xlCSV  6  CSV
xlCSVMac  22  Macintosh CSV
xlCSVMSDOS  24  MSDOS CSV
xlCSVWindows  23  Windows CSV

---

Now here’s where the interesting part happens… Excel by default will use a comma as the delimiter, but if you open up Control Panel –> Region and Language, and then click the Additional settings button on the bottom…

Now look very closely at the “List separator” item, which normally has a comma in the field, but for the purposes of illustration I’ve switched it to a Pipe character.

[List separator Change](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/)

[image]

I hope this helps!

End solution in short example: `for VBScript`
(place in file *.vbs)

```
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Path = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName,WScript.ScriptName, "")
Set objWorkBook = objXL.Workbooks.Open(Path & "file_temp")

objXL.DisplayAlerts = False

'eight comma
objWorkBook.WorkSheets("Sales").SaveAs Path & "abc_sales", 23 , , , , , , , , True

'clean up
objWorkBook.Close
objXL.Quit
Set objXL = Nothing
Set objWorkBook = Nothing
```

Script make file `abc_sales` (type of CSV) in folder of script and with file `file_temp` (type of Excel with 1 sheet "Sales").

Delimiter set in field `List Separator`above

[image: Delimiter set in field <code>List Separator</code>]

or Full automatic variant:

```
strDelimiter = "|"
strDelimiterPath = "HKCU\Control Panel\International\sList"

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strOldDelimiter = WshShell.RegRead(strDelimiterPath)
WshShell.RegWrite strDelimiterPath, strDelimiter, "REG_SZ"

Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
strPath = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName,WScript.ScriptName, "")
Set objWorkBook = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strPath & "file_temp")

objXL.DisplayAlerts = False

'eight comma
objWorkBook.WorkSheets("Sales").SaveAs Path & "abc_sales", 23 , , , , , , , , True

'clean up
WshShell.RegWrite strDelimiterPath, strOldDelimiter, "REG_SZ"
objWorkBook.Close
objXL.Quit
Set objXL = Nothing
Set objWorkBook = Nothing
```

---

End solution in short example: for `VBА`
(place in module of `file_temp.xlsm`)

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Sub Sheets2CSV()
Set awb = ActiveWorkbook
Sheets.Copy
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    'only saveAS sheets that are NOT empty
    If Sheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        Sheet.Rows(1).Delete  ' this will remove Row 1 or the header Row
        Select Case Sheet.Name
        Case "Sales"
            Sheet.SaveAs awb.Path & "\abc_sales", xlCSVWindows, local:=True
        Case "Goals"
            Sheet.SaveAs awb.Path & "\abc_file_goals", xlCSVWindows, local:=True
        Case "Commissions"
            Sheet.SaveAs awb.Path & "\abc_file_coms", xlCSVWindows, local:=True
        Case Else
            Sheet.SaveAs awb.Path & "\abc_file_sheet_" & Sheet.Name, xlCSVWindows, local:=True
        End Select
    End If
Next
ActiveWorkbook.Close 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried its vbscript translation but did not work, will update after trying more options.

Comment: (Sheet.SaveAs Filename:=strScriptPath & "abc_sales" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows, local:=True) tested OK

Comment: Sheet.SaveAs strScriptPath & "abc_sales" & ".csv", xlCSVWindows, local:=True

Comment: Variant II, Syntax! Attention!

Comment: This isn't VBA it's VBScript the OP is using, it will generate syntax errors as syntax like `FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows` is not recognised.

Comment: TY, You are absolutely right! it is not VBA. 1) for VBA -  local:=True 2) for VBScript , , , , , , , True) position number 12...  Attention to  correct value of variable `local`. Syntax there

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280325/how-to-convert-excel-to-semicolon-or-pipe-delimited-file-using-script/47288561#comment81513715_47280325), you must define the Named Constants as VBScript doesn't have access to the Excel Object Type Library so has no idea how to associate them to their numeric values.

VBScript also doesn't support Named Parameters syntax such as this<sup>#</sup>;

```vb
Sheet.SaveAs Filename:=strScriptPath & "abc_sales" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows, local:=True
```

will fail with a

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error:
> Syntax error

as `Filename:=` means nothing to VBScript.

Instead, you want to do something like this;

```vb
'Define your Named Constants
'XlFileFormat Enumeration
Const xlCSVWindows = 23

'...

'SaveAs call should match the number of arguments (optional or not).
Call sheet.SaveAs(strScriptPath & "abc.csv", xlCSVWindows, , , , , , , , , , True)
```

*<sup><sup>`...`</sup> - Denotes existing code not included for the example.</sup>*

---

#### Useful Links

- [XlFileFormat Enumeration (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel)
- [Workbook.SaveAs Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel)

---

*<sup><sup>#</sup> - Answer based off [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280325/how-to-convert-excel-to-semicolon-or-pipe-delimited-file-using-script#comment81516514_47281574) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281574/692942</sup>*